# Setup a git server on a windows

Tags: windows, git, ssh

I want to setup a Git server on a windows machine. I wanted to set it up on an apache server. I know it can be done, but cannot find any documentation on how to do. Do you know any documentation I can user? Rather than HTTP, I would like to set it up over SSH. But can't find any SSH servers for windows. Do you know how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe a combination of [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/) and [TortoiseGit](http://code.google.com/p/tortoisegit/) for your clients might do the job.

Here is a blog post that documents this process reasonably well: http://therightstuff.de/CommentView,guid,b969ea4d-8d2c-42af-9806-de3631f4df68.aspx